# APC (variable cache) alternative for PHP running as CGI

Tags: php, caching, apc

I am wondering what other simple-to-use caching mechanisms exist for PHP, except APC cache, that work fine with php running as CGI.

Configure Command
`'./configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/php5' '--enable-force-cgi-redirect' '--enable-fastcgi' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php5/cgi' '--with-curl=/usr/local/lib' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-kerberos' '--with-openssl' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-mhash' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr/local' '--with-pdo-mysql=/usr' '--with-pear' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--enable-zip' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-iconv=/usr/local' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-mbstring'`

Server API `CGI/FastCGI`

What I am looking for is a simple memory caching system, that allows me to store variables, set TTL, and then retrieve them from memory. I am NOT looking for opcode cache.

**NOTE**: I cannot switch to PHP CLI or other SAPI. I've also tried installing APC on this environment and it works just per request (can not be accessed on refresh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for Memcached  http://www.memcached.org/

PHP has a module for it: http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php

Answer (score 3):

Given that you say that you can't switch to fcgi/fpm I assume that you don't have root access to your server (if this assumption is wrong, then please, just switch, it will not only make APC work but also improve the performance in general.)

So the only thing that I can think of is just using MySQL for this. MySQL has MEMORY tables which are stored in RAM. You could easily build a key => value cache on top of that. Obviously this won't deliver the same performance as APC, but maybe it suffices for your case.

Comment: i DO have root access. However, i need the php scripts to be executed by the owner, and not apache:apache, that's why I use CGI and not CLI

Comment: Then have a look at *mpm-itk* - it does exactly what you're trying to archive with CGI.

Comment: @develroot I'm not sure I understand your problem. If you use php-fpm you start the processes under a different user anyways.

Comment: @NikiC i do not currently use php-fpm.

Comment: @develroot That's what I mean: You should switch ;) fastcgi is - well, as the name already says - significantly faster than cgi.